# PayPal Adaptive Payments vs Braintree Merchants

Tags: python, django, paypal, braintree

Which is better considering this situation - using PayPal adaptive payments for parallel payment processing and integration, or using a Braintree merchants account for payment processing and syncing with a 3rd-party for payment integration? Can PayPal adaptive payments do it all?

Suppose you have a business called Sewing Bliss & Co. It has two founders. One founder lives in NYC and creates baby clothing, the other founder lives in CA and creates quilts. They both sell their products through their ecommerce web app called www.sewingbliss.co.

But, they want their income to be organized into two separate streams - whenever a visitor purchases a baby item it goes into the NYC founder's PayPal account. And whenever a quilt is purchased it goes to the CA founder's PayPal account. If a customer purchases both a baby item and a quilt in one transaction, the transaction goes through and is divided up respectively. To the customer, the transaction appears seamless.

I am a web developer (mostly Python/Django). I am curious how this would best be implemented. Any insights?

Comment: @jay unfortunately, not yet!

Answer (score 0):

So I image you would have two different pages, one for the quilt and one for the baby items. Now you could set up individual PayPal buttons for each page in which each button will send money to a different account. I would suggest checking out [django-paypal](https://django-paypal.readthedocs.io).

The documentation on django-paypal can be a little confusing so read carefully.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, however, this solution does not take into account when a buyer has both a quilt and a baby item in one cart. Theoretically, they might want to buy both in one transaction, rather than make them click a button twice and checkout twice.